# Double slit experiment, leave the detector but stop us knowing the result

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

This may be an amateur question, however here goes.

I understand the double slit experiment creates a situation where detecting which slit the particle/wave goes through causes a collapse of the wave function and for the particle to act like a particle and not cause an interference pattern.

What I want to know is this:

If say for example, the detector emits a signal to a speaker if it detects the particle and the speaker emits an audible sound, my understanding is that the wave function would collapse - we measured the outcome.  However, what if we left the detector doing its thing, but turned off the speaker so that we didn't know? Would this still be considered "measurement" or does measurement require recording/knowledge (future included) of the outcome?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Knowing. The moon is still there even when your not looking at it.

Comment: Quantum computer builders fighting unwanted wavefunction collapse would love it if they could fix the problem by looking away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exact answer to your question: you do NOT need to know the which-slit information for the type of collapse you describe to occur.  It is enough that the mere possibility of obtaining that information exists for the double slit pattern to change from one showing interference to that of no interference.

Specifically: You can place a polarizer over each of the 2 slits (2 polarizers total).  They can be oriented either parallel or perpendicular to each other.  When they are parallel, the usual interference pattern appears for photons going through the slits.  However, when those polarizers are oriented instead perpendicular to each other (orthogonal), something interesting happens.  The perpendicular outputs of the slits allow one, in principle, to know which slit any particular photon went through.  Note that we don't actually change anything in the setup to obtain this information.  (You could do that by analyzing the photons as the arrive at the screen.)  So... the observer does not know which slit the particle goes through, and the interference effect still disappears.

Experimental demonstration of this:
https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

Compare figures 8 and 9, and look at the text "E. Which-path marker".  So for your analogy: it doesn't matter whether the speaker is turned on or off.  The existence of an observer is definitely not the deciding factor.  The deciding factor is the presence - or not - of a which path marker, as the experiment clearly shows.